# Custom MatFormFieldControl not showing initial value in view

Tags: angular, angular-material, controlvalueaccessor, mat-form-field, mat-select

Check the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-components-demo-5k6gey?file=src/app/app.component.html

When it has an initial value, it is not shown in the view, and when try to clear its value, its still showed buggly. The internal value is always correct, the problem is the view. The "clear value" button is also bugged, it internally clears the value correctly, but the value is shown bugged in the view.

I have already try 1000 things, including emitModelToViewChange: true, changeDetector, read every StackOverflow/GitHub post, etc. Using compareFn shows a view initial value of All (which is incorrect, because it should show "11" instead of "", and it doesn't fix the "clear value" bug.

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with your `mat-searchable-select` component. If you replace that with a plain `mat-select`, everything works as expected. You might want to look into how to properly implement `MatFormFieldControl`.

Comment: Take a look at [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ThVof0Rz64), he's doing a good job explaining how to build custom material form field controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed both errors by adding this to the caller (app.component.html) of mat-searchable-select

```
[value]="searchGroup.get(filter.key)?.value"
```

and this to the mat-searchable-select.html

```
[value]="value"
```